# How do I get Node list?

Tags: vbscript

Trying to list Nodes with `<EventID>1</EventID>` But I get an error
It is expecting a node test.

I have the following code but when I run it I get the following error:

[image: error image]

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

```
dim xml,node,nodes,Root,strNames
'Set xml =  CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
Set xml =  CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")
xml.Async = False
xml.Load "C:\Test\Week\cr_history.txt"
xml.setProperty "SelectionLanguage","XPath"


For Each Node in xml.selectnodes("//DS001History/[@EventID='1']")
  strNames=Node.name
Next
msgbox strNames
```

Comment: Where is your xml ? What nodes are you trying to fetch? Without this info, how do you expect others to help?

Comment: Please post your xml or you wont get any help

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your xpath to `//DS001History/EventID[number(text())=1]`. This will fetch all EventIDs with a value of 1 under DS001History. Note that I also used `number()` to ensure that I match only numeric values. You can use `//DS001History/EventID[text()=1]` or `//DS001History/EventID[text()='1']` as well.

If you want to fetch ALL EventIDs with a value of 1, you can simply use `//EventID[text()=1]`. There is no need to give the parent's path in xpath query.

Try the following code

```
dim xml,node,nodes,Root,strNames
Set xml =  CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")
xml.Async = False
xml.Load "C:\Users\pankaj.jaju\Desktop\test.xml"
xml.setProperty "SelectionLanguage","XPath"

strNames = ""
For Each Node in xml.selectnodes("//DS001History/EventID[number(text())=1]")
  strNames = strNames & Node.tagname
Next
msgbox strNames
```